# Am I allowed to own a foreign flag?

Tags: regulations, souvenirs

Sometimes I buy the local flag of a country I have visited as a souvenir.

Given that there is such a thing as a [flag instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_protocol), which in some countries is embedded into either criminal or civil law, I am wondering if I am even allowed to buy a foreign flag. Not living in the country of the flag, the countries don't have jurisdiction to enforce their flag protocol, so I could imagine that it is not allowed to own a foreign flag in some cases. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Keep in mind also that a 3 foot by 4 foot officially fringed and whatnot piece of cloth is a Flag, while a little 3 in by 4 inch piece of plastic may not be - and whatever rules about folding, respecting etc apply to the large thing may not apply to the small replica you are more likely to want as a souvenir

Answer (score 4):

You're affected by the laws of the country where you currently are. So if the country laws prohibit owning any specific flag - you'd better obey. Countries typically only care about their own flags.

However the Wikipedia article you linked to describes *use* of flags and that doesn't include owning the flag. Common restrictions may include:

- prohibition of burning or otherwise destroying the flag in public or demonstrating the process - that can qualify as state symbol desecration
- prohibition of using the flag or a fabric colored as a flag as clothes and especially underwear - for example pants with USA "stars-and-stripes" flag on the butt could qualify as offense
- prohibition of public display of the flag other than during state holidays and on state property - for example, you may be disallowed to display the flag on a private house because it's not a governmental institution

This applies in most cases. In case of doubt check for local regulations in advance. [This Wikipedia article may be a good start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_desecration).

Comment: wow. Growing up in the UK I find it astonishing that these rules exist and people are concerned about flags. I can't even remember how many I have damaged, torn, converted into clothes, painted, burned, slid down mountains on etc (but all of them were European or commonwealth flags, so no worries about strange rules there)

Comment: *for example pants with USA "stars-and-stripes" flag on the butt could qualify as offense* - Where is this an offense?

Comment: There's no criminal law in the US prohibiting using the flag as an item of clothing AFAIK. Falls under the 1st amendment. In other countries, such do indeed exist.

Comment: And of course most countries have no laws against using other countries' flags, except some will have laws prohibiting the public display/flying of them, especially instead of or at higher mast than their own (the US does have that, by US flag protocol their flag must ALWAYS be flown from a higher position than any other in its vicinity).

Comment: This reminds me of an interesting story from a few years ago in Germany during the world cup: ***[World Cup Patriotism in Berlin: Immigrants Defend the Flag While Left-Wing Germans Tear It Down](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/world-cup-patriotism-in-berlin-immigrants-defend-the-flag-while-left-wing-germans-tear-it-down-a-703533.html)***

Comment: What about non-country flags?

Comment: What about flags of enemy countries? Or of disputed territories? Should I take my Israel flag to Iran and my Palestine flag to Israel and my Nagorno Karabakh flag to Azerbaijan? Also I believe there are several countries beside Germany which prohibit or restrict flags of former fascist or totalitarian regimes.

Comment: @hippietrail: I've heard of an incident when Azerbaijan put a person onto permanent no-entry list for having visited Nagorno Karabakh. So I'd say you shouldn't toy with taking country A flag to country B when A and B actively dislike each other.